# STM32G051K8U7 microcontroller project build problem while transitioning from Arm Compiler v5.06 to Arm Compiler v6.20.1

Tags: compiler-errors, arm, stm32, keil

Simple problem:

Started an STM32G051K8U7 microcontroller project using Arm Compiler v6.20.1 in Keil uVision IDE, built a project all good, everything works just fine can debug the program using ST-Link debugger - no problems.
And at some point I decided to compile the program with Arm Compiler v5.06 - all good! However, I wanted to revert back to Arm Compiler v6.20.1 and it would not build it anymore. I have no idea what happened, no files actually got changed in my project directory, but there are 247 errors complaining about the startup file. After this I can still always build it with v5.06, but not with any of v6.2x versions.

Any Idea how I can bypass this issue? It happened to both computers using different MDK Arm versions.

Note: I removed some error lines since they are all related to the same problem and should not be investigated separately.

The build output is below:

```
Build started: Project: ICFW70102
*** Using Compiler 'V6.20.1', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCLANG-v6.20.1\Bin'
Build target 'STM32G051K8Ux'
compiling ICFW70102_it.c...
compiling main.c...
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(1): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;******************************************************************************
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(2): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* File Name          : startup_stm32g051xx.s
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(3): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* Author             : MCD Application Team
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(4): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* Description        : STM32G051xx devices vector table for MDK-ARM toolchain.
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(5): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                      This module performs:
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(6): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                      - Set the initial SP
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(7): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                      - Set the initial PC == Reset_Handler
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(8): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                      - Set the vector table entries with the exceptions ISR address
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(9): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                      - Branches to __main in the C library (which eventually
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(10): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                        calls main()).
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(11): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                      After Reset the CortexM0 processor is in Thread mode,
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(12): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*                      priority is Privileged, and the Stack is set to Main.
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(13): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* <<< Use Configuration Wizard in Context Menu >>>
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(14): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;******************************************************************************
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(15): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* @attention
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(16): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(17): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* Copyright (c) 2018-2021 STMicroelectronics.
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(18): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* All rights reserved.
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(19): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(20): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(21): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* in the root directory of this software component.
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(22): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;* If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(23): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(24): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;******************************************************************************
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(25): error: unexpected token in argument list
; Amount of memory (in bytes) allocated for Stack
            ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(26): error: unexpected token in argument list
; Tailor this value to your application needs
              ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(27): error: unexpected token at start of statement
; <h> Stack Configuration
  ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(28): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;   <o> Stack Size (in Bytes) <0x0-0xFFFFFFFF:8>
    ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(29): error: unexpected token at start of statement
; </h>
  ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(31): error: unexpected token in argument list
Stack_Size      EQU     0x00000400
                        ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(33): error: unexpected token in argument list
                AREA    STACK, NOINIT, READWRITE, ALIGN=3
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(34): error: unexpected token in argument list
Stack_Mem       SPACE   Stack_Size
                        ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(35): error: invalid instruction
__initial_sp
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(91): error: unexpected token in argument list
                DCD     TIM1_CC_IRQHandler             ; TIM1 Capture Compare
                                                                      ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(92): error: invalid instruction, did you mean: adc, add?
                DCD     TIM2_IRQHandler                ; TIM2
                ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(92): error: invalid instruction
                DCD     TIM2_IRQHandler                ; TIM2
                                                         ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(93): error: invalid instruction, did you mean: adc, add?
                DCD     TIM3_IRQHandler                ; TIM3
                ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(93): error: invalid instruction
                DCD     TIM3_IRQHandler                ; TIM3
                                                         ^
                EXPORT  ADC1_COMP_IRQHandler           [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(165): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQHandler [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(166): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM1_CC_IRQHandler             [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(167): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM2_IRQHandler                [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(168): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM3_IRQHandler                [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(169): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM6_DAC_LPTIM1_IRQHandler     [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(170): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM7_LPTIM2_IRQHandler         [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(171): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM14_IRQHandler               [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(172): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM15_IRQHandler               [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(173): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM16_IRQHandler               [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(174): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  TIM17_IRQHandler               [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(175): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  I2C1_IRQHandler                [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(176): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  I2C2_IRQHandler                [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(177): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  SPI1_IRQHandler                [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(178): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  SPI2_IRQHandler                [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(179): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  USART1_IRQHandler              [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(180): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  USART2_IRQHandler              [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(181): error: unexpected token in argument list
                EXPORT  LPUART1_IRQHandler             [WEAK]
                                                       ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(184): error: invalid instruction
WWDG_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(185): error: invalid instruction
PVD_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(186): error: invalid instruction
RTC_TAMP_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(187): error: invalid instruction
FLASH_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(188): error: invalid instruction
RCC_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(189): error: invalid instruction
EXTI0_1_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(190): error: invalid instruction
EXTI2_3_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(191): error: invalid instruction
EXTI4_15_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(192): error: invalid instruction
DMA1_Channel1_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(193): error: invalid instruction
DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(194): error: invalid instruction
DMA1_Ch4_7_DMAMUX1_OVR_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(195): error: invalid instruction
ADC1_COMP_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(196): error: invalid instruction
TIM1_BRK_UP_TRG_COM_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(197): error: invalid instruction
TIM1_CC_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(198): error: invalid instruction
TIM2_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(199): error: invalid instruction
TIM3_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(200): error: invalid instruction
TIM6_DAC_LPTIM1_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(201): error: invalid instruction
TIM7_LPTIM2_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(202): error: invalid instruction
TIM14_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(203): error: invalid instruction
TIM15_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(204): error: invalid instruction
TIM16_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(205): error: invalid instruction
TIM17_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(206): error: invalid instruction
I2C1_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(207): error: invalid instruction
I2C2_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(208): error: invalid instruction
SPI1_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(209): error: invalid instruction
SPI2_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(210): error: invalid instruction
USART1_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(211): error: invalid instruction
USART2_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(212): error: invalid instruction
LPUART1_IRQHandler
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(216): error: invalid instruction
                ENDP
                ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(218): error: invalid instruction
                ALIGN
                ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(220): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*******************************************************************************
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(221): error: unexpected token in argument list
; User Stack and Heap initialization
             ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(222): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;*******************************************************************************
 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(223): error: invalid instruction
                 IF      :DEF:__MICROLIB
                              ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(225): error: invalid instruction
                 EXPORT  __initial_sp
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(226): error: invalid instruction
                 EXPORT  __heap_base
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(227): error: invalid instruction
                 EXPORT  __heap_limit
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(229): error: invalid instruction
                 ELSE
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(231): error: invalid instruction
                 IMPORT  __use_two_region_memory
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(232): error: invalid instruction
                 EXPORT  __user_initial_stackheap
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(234): error: invalid instruction
__user_initial_stackheap
^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(242): error: invalid instruction
                 ALIGN
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(244): error: invalid instruction
                 ENDIF
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(246): error: invalid instruction, did you mean: and?
                 END
                 ^
RTE/Device/STM32G051K8Ux/startup_stm32g051xx.s(248): error: unexpected token at start of statement
;************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE*****
 ^
assembling startup_stm32g051xx.s...
compiling system_stm32g0xx.c...
compiling ICFW70102.c...
".\Objects\ICFW70102.axf" - 247 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:02
```

Comment: Is `startup_stm32g051xx.s` a file from your project, or distributed with the compiler?

Comment: It is unique to each target device. I solved the problem already. Thanks for taking your time to look into this.

Answer (score -1):

I found an issue, it appears that this is got to do with Assembler option settings.

[image]

I hope this is of some use to others as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).